# Active Directory Force Update Fails

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

[image]

I tried looking up this error and problem and found nothing.

Could this be a firewall issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if they are XP, I don't think it'll work at all.

But yes, there are firewall settings that must be allowed/set in order for Remote Refresh to work properly.

See here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj572986.aspx

[image]

Also note:

> **Configure firewall rules by creating a GPO from the Group Policy Remote Update Firewall Ports Starter GPO and linking to the domain**
>
> In Windows Server 2012, Group Policy adds a new Starter GPO called
>   Group Policy Remote Update Firewall Ports. This Starter GPO includes
>   policy settings to configure the firewall rules that are specified in
>   the previous table. This enables inbound network traffic on the ports,
>   which is necessary to allow the remote Group Policy refresh to run. It
>   is a best practice to create a new GPO from this Starter GPO, and then
>   link the new GPO to your domain with a higher precedence than the
>   Default Domain GPO, so that you can configure all computers in the
>   domain to enable a remote Group Policy refresh.

Comment: Disabled firewalls and it worked. Guess they are not enabled by default like one would assume when connecting to domain networks.

Comment: I think you meant "not *disabled* by default..." right?  However, in best practice it is better to not disable the firewall even on the domain.   But that's a "do it how you feel best for your company" issue IMO.

Comment: Oh what I meant was I figured the ports mentioned above would become open by default when you connect to a domain.

Comment: Ah...gotcha.  Correct...